# Работа с массивами np.array в python - как умножить массивы матриц одинаковой длины поэлементно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, numpy, матрицы

Есть метод np.dot, позволяющий умножать пару матриц. Есть ли какой-то синтаксис или другой метод, позволяющий по двум массивам матриц одинаковой длины построить массив, состоящий из произведений матриц с одинаковыми индексами?
P.S. реализовать это одним циклом очень просто, но время работы слишком большое. хотелось бы, чтобы умножение происходило параллельно, желательно методам numpy

Comment: можете привести в вопросе небольшие примеры входных матриц и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: x=[[[1, 0],[0,1]], [[2,0],[0,2]]] y=x, на выходе хочу prod(x,y)=[[[1, 0],[0,1]], [[4,0],[0,4]]]

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: какую размерность имеют "массивы матриц"?

Comment: массивы матриц размерности 1. исходные данные по сути массивы размерности 3

Comment: [что делать с ответами на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;-)

Comment: Перенесите пожалуйста комментарии в тело вопроса кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1071831/edit). Комментарии служат только для уточнений, обычно удаляются, и не являются дополняющей частью вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
x = np.array([[[1, 0],[0,1]], [[2,0],[0,2]]])
y = x
print("shape of 'x': {}".format(x.shape))

res = x * y
print(res)
```

вывод:

```
shape of 'x': (2, 2, 2)

[[[1 0]
  [0 1]]

 [[4 0]
  [0 4]]]
```

---

PS если `x` - представляет из себя список матриц одинаковой размерности, то его можно легко переделать в 3D матрицу:

```
In [90]: x = [np.array([[1, 0],[0,1]]), np.array([[2,0],[0,2]])]

In [91]: x
Out[91]:
[array([[1, 0],
        [0, 1]]), array([[2, 0],
        [0, 2]])]

In [92]: x = np.asarray(x)

In [93]: x
Out[93]:
array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[2, 0],
        [0, 2]]])

In [94]: x.shape
Out[94]: (2, 2, 2)
```